# Favicon not showing even after cache cleared

Tags: html, favicon

For some reason, the favicon just isn't showing. The website is [gracedli.com](https://gracedli.com).

You can see the favicon at [gracedli.com/favicon.ico](https://gracedli.com/favicon.ico) and my code to add it is (currently only on index.html):

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

I've cleared the cache and used multiple different browsers, and for the life of me, I can't figure it out. Would love some help on it (everything's written in pure HTML/CSS so you can take a peek at the full code at the link). Thank you so much!

Comment: I checked the html, and it looks like you have put the contents of <head> in <header> instead. Move them into <head>, and that would possibly solve your problem.

Comment: @TimmyChan yep, that was the problem. Wow, not sure how I completely missed that. Thank you!! (I'll add an answer citing you with this as the reason and mark that as accepted—but if you turn this into an answer, I'll just accept that)

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put the contents of `<head>` in `<header>` instead. Move them into , and that would possibly solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Common reasons your Favicon is not showing

1. Check file path : You need to ensure that your favicon’s file path is correct.
2. The link of favicon is not at the right location : It is important to place the link to add your favicon in the head section of your webpage.
3. Syntax errors : A minor syntax error in the link of favicons could result in your favicon not showing.
4. When favicon file in the root directory, but not linked : Always put the favicon in the root directory, and name it favicon.ico. Almost all modern browsers look up /favicon.ico by default but make sure that you have these links in your head section:

- link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
- link rel=" bookmark" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  Because in many cases Just because the favicon file is in your root directory, it does not mean that it will automatically recognize.

5. Your browser has cached your site as one without a favicon : May be your browser has ‘saved’ your site as one without a favicon. You need to clear the cache in your browser or use a different browser.
   May it helped to solve the issue…

Answer (score 0):

Huge shout out to Timmy Chan (in the comments of the question) for noticing this, but I put my tags in `<header>` instead of `<head>`. Once I moved them, it worked!